# Creating a Dictionary in C# from an existing array

Tags: c#

I have an existing string array that contains pairs of items. I need to create a dictionary from that existing array. The Array contains pairs similar to: 
Apple, A,
Banana, B,
Cantalope, C
...
...

How do I assign the fruit as the key and the letter as the value in the dictionary?
Is there a way to do it without rewriting the array values??

---

NOW THAT WE HAVE THE DICTIONARY WRITTEN.....
I need the program to scan a list of fruit and evey time the key Banana appears, I need to output the value B.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are *the letters* unique? Dictionary keys have to be unique.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how your array is?

Comment: Array has many kinds of form, so an example of input would be better.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your array.  Is it `string[,]`, `string[]`, or `string`?

Comment: You can easily get the first letter of the word and add to a dictionary. you will need to check if array item is just one letter than you will skip it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a really simple example, be sure to check the bounds of your array and such.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

//Make sure your array has an even number of values
if (myArray.Length % 2 != 0) 
    throw new Exception("Array has odd number of elements!");

foreach (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i+=2)
{
    myDict.Add(myArray[i], myArray[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: You got in before me, I shall delete my identical answer. Sometimes the simplest way is the best.

Comment: Yeah I like my answer still but this is simpler. Better to use `+=2` than have the mod conditional. This probably performs ~twice as well.

Comment: Although I think you might want `.Add(myArray[i], myArray[i + 1])`

Comment: @BinaryWorrier In OPs example the key comes second, and key is the first parameter of `Add`.  EDIT oh just kidding I just reread it, fixing now.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia well he doesn't actually specify that but it seems like the odd indexes are probably the keys.

Comment: @Kevin You need the mod conditional, or you will end up with an Index Out of Range Exception in your loop when the array length is odd.

Comment: Very new to programming. I believe this example will accomplish exactly what I need it to. Piecing through this, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @EtherDragon I know, the comment is there to warn, I could think of quite a few edge cases, but I left them for OP since the question is a bit vague.

Comment: @Binary Worrier I noticed the same thing about the [i+1] and [i] being switched. luckily I'm not so novice that I didn't pick up on that. :)  If nothing else, I can try it both ways and see which works.

Comment: I added the check for array length, but you may also want to put in a check to make sure all your keys are unique

Comment: keys are unique, values are not.  Shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

For LINQ 'one-liner' enthusiasts:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length / 2)
          .ToDictionary(i => myArray[2*i], 
                        i => myArray[2*i+1])
```

Not the most readable piece of code one might make to solve this problem, though.

Comment: Cool but seriously lacking in error checking. What happens if `myArray.Lenght % 2 == 1` ?

Comment: That depends on what kind of way you want to signal your error. If an IndexOutOfRange exception is sufficient, write `(myArray.Length + 1)/2`. If you want to verify uniqueness of the key, the Dictionary does that for you. If you want to produce a custom message/exception, might as well do your own validation anyway.

Comment: I guess it comes down to preference but I would never let an `IndexOutOfRangeException` go unhandled. I don't consider that to be an exceptional occurrence. This code should probably be in a helper method wrapped in a try-catch.

Comment: @DoomMuffins I like this one (which is why I upvoted), but I believe you need to switch indexes for key and value.

Comment: You're right, OP wrote that the fruits are the keys and the letters are the values, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

A little work with the modulus operator will do it for you. First I make sure the array has an even number of elements. Then I take every even index and add it plus the next as the key and value. Perhaps you'll want to flip those (not sure if your key or value is first in the array) but this should basically work as is.

```
Dictionary<string, string> kvs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (array.Length % 2 == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            kvs.Add(array[i], array[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
else
   // we have a problem with our array
```

Comment: Or possibly increase your loop counter by 2 instead of 1 and not need the modulus operator?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Use `i+=2` instead of `i++` for this loop

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I agree that is better. I'm just going to leave this since it is different and does work. It should still be helpful since it gives insight into the problem.

Comment: I say, steal the other's ideas shamelessly (but thank them), as yours is the most complete answer (IMO) given that you check the length of the array to ensure it is even.

Comment: @EtherDragon lol I could do that but I don't see the point now. The other answer has too much momentum. I will happily accept my one upvote.

Comment: I up-vote any answers that contributes something new.

Comment: @EtherDragon the one advantage to my answers is that I usually offer some explanation of my reasoning. The others just give the beginning developer some code to copy and paste which will result in them learning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need something like this:

```
var fruits = new string[] { "Apple, A", "Banana, B", "Cantalope, C" };
var fruitDict = fruits.Select(f => f.Split(',')).ToDictionary(f => f[0].Trim(), f => f[1].Trim());
foreach (var fruit in fruitDict)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", fruit.Key, fruit.Value);
```

And if I did not and it is a sequential array:

```
var fruits = new string[] { "Apple" , "A", "Banana", "B", "Cantalope", "C" };
var fruitDict = fruits
    .Select((f, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? new { Name = f, Cat = fruits[i + 1] } : null)
    .Where(f => f != null)
    .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.Cat);
foreach (var fruit in fruitDict)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", fruit.Key, fruit.Value);
```